# Issues with .keystore file

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

I am having issues with converting between `.P7B` to `.PFX` using a `.keystore` private key file 
It produces the error

```
unable to load private key 2388:error:0909006C:PEM
```

when i run the command

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey privatekey.keystore -in cert.cer
```

please help

Comment: I see no p7b in your question. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#keystore-types), a keystore is most likely **The proprietary keystore implementation provided by** and nothing that openSSL can convert.

As far as I know only java implementations can do this. Here are some tools that might help:

- http://portecle.sourceforge.net/
- https://keystore-explorer.org/index.html

Comment: Although a Java keystore can be, and for j9 up (since 2018) by default is, PKCS12, which already _is_ PFX (and can be handled by OpenSSL, though not in a context where PEM _key_ rather than p12 is required).

Comment: If so renaming `privatekey.keystore` to `cert.pfx` would do the job